# Java 10 and the Mac application menu

Tags: java, macos, java-10

I am having difficulty getting an app working with the application menu on the Mac using Java 10. Specifically, I would like to have a Preferences item on the menu and to know when Preferences and Quit have been clicked so I can add code. This facility used to be provided by com.apple.eawt but that has been removed.

[Removed macOS-Specific Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-97C1D0BB-D5D3-4CAD-B17D-03A87A0AAF3B) says

> java.awt.Desktop class contains replacements for the APIs in the
>   Apple–specific com.apple.eawt

I looked at [JEP 272](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272) but, probably because I'm new to Java, I can't see how to use the code there to deal with the Mac menu. Extensive searches haven't come up with anything.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help, for example, by showing how clicking on Quit could give an "Are you sure?" alert.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, the handler gets set in the Desktop object. Doc at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#setPreferencesHandler-java.awt.desktop.PreferencesHandler-

I can knock an example up for you in a day or two but hopefully the link above will get you started. You need to check the preferences action is supported, the doc there says how too. Apologies, if you’re new to java this may not be enough without the example but I’m maxed for the next few days.

Comment: Thank you for your offer of an example. Unfortunately my Java skills are not good enough to put the linked details into practice, so such an example would be gratefully received whenever you have the time to do so.

Comment: Alvin Alexander has just published [Java 10: How to implement About, Preferences, and Quit menu items on MacOS](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/java-macos-about-preferences-quit-handlers-desktop-awt) which works well.